# Saving multiple IDs in a HasMany Eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a model `Foo`, which has many `Bar`s:

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    public function bars()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Bar');
    }
}

class Bar extends Model
{
    public function foo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Foo');
    }
}
```

When saving a new `Foo`, the request payload comes with an array of `Bar` ids. I want to save these at the same time. This works:

```
public function store(StoreFoo $request)
{
    $foo = Foo::create($request->validated());
    foreach ($request->barIds as $barId) {
        $foo->bars()->create(['bar_id' => $barId]);
    }
}
```

My question is: is there a way to do this without a loop? I've tried `sync` and `attach` but these aren't applicable in this case.

Comment: There's `createMany()` but that doesn't really simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of that you can achieve this without writing a loop yourself is by using the `saveMany` method on the `HasMany` relation. You can create instances of your `Bar` model and pass them all as an array to the `saveMany` method and that will save all of them and return an array of the created entities in response.

```
$foo->bars()->saveMany([new Bar(['id' => 1]), new Bar(['id' => 2])]);
```

That being said, Laravel uses a loop to save these models one by one under the hood so it doesn't really do much different to what you're doing now.

Similarly, there's also a `createMany` method that you can use in the same way as `saveMany` but instead of providing newly created models, you can provide arrays of attributes instead.

Comment: But if I don't know in advance how big the `$request->barIds` array will be, I don't think I can use this, right?

Comment: I suppose it all depends on what your input could be. If you have a one to many relationship (it looks like you do), then perhaps you could use the `Model::insert()` method to bulk create the *many* model. If the `barIds` coming from your request is an array, you could convert it to a collection and chunk it so you're only inserting X records at a time.

Answer (score 0):

migration table sample

```
Schema::create('logs', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->default(0)->index();
    $table->string('type', 10)->index(); // add, update, delete
    $table->string('table', 50)->index();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('row');
    $table->dateTime('created_at');
});
Schema::create('log_fields', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('log_id')->index();
    $table->string('field', 50)->index();
    $table->longText('old');
    $table->longText('new');
});
```

model Log.php file

```
class Log extends Model
{
    const UPDATED_AT = null;
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'type',
        'table',
        'row'
    ];

    public function logFields()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(LogField::class);
    }
}
```

model LogField.php file

```
class LogField extends Model
{
    public    $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable   = [
        'field',
        'old',
        'new'
    ];

    public function log()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Log::class);
    }
}
```

boot function for another model for save change in database.
hook created, updating and deleting for answer your question

```
public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::created(function($resorce) {
            $_log = new Log;
            $_log->create([
                'user_id' => session('uid', 0),
                'type'    => 'add',
                'table'   => $resorce->getTable(),
                'row'     => $resorce->fresh()->toArray()['id']
            ]);

            return true;
        });

        static::updating(function($resorce) {
            $_log = new Log;
            $log = $_log->create([
                'user_id' => session('uid', 0),
                'type'    => 'update',
                'table'   => $resorce->getTable(),
                'row'     => $resorce->fresh()->toArray()['id']
            ]);

            foreach($resorce->getDirty() as $field => $new) {
                $log->logFields()->create([
                    'field'  => $field,
                    'old'    => $resorce->fresh()->toArray()[$field],
                    'new'    => $new
                ]);
            }

            return true;
        });

        static::deleting(function($resorce) {
            $_log = new Log;
            $log = $_log->create([
                'user_id' => session('uid', 0),
                'type'    => 'delete',
                'table'   => $resorce->getTable(),
                'row'     => $resorce->id,
            ]);

            foreach($resorce->fresh()->toArray() as $field => $value) {
                $log->logFields()->create([
                    'field'  => $field,
                    'old'    => '',
                    'new'    => $value
                ]);
            }

            return true;
        });
    }
```

Hope I have helped you to understand this.